# Как с помощью echo вывести содержимое result?

Tags: php, sql

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT first_name FROM example1");
```

Как с помощью echo вывести содержимое result?

Answer (score 0):

Функция mysqli_query() возвращает объект типа mysqli_result, либо false. С помощью echo его не выведешь. Самый простой способ вывести его на экран для дебага:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT first_name FROM example1");
if ($result) {
    $arr = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Функция mysqli_fetch_all() извлекает все данные из результата и помещает их в массив. Тип массива задаётся вторым параметром.